# How to change data-zoom-image value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm using elevate zoom effects for zooming facility of image, my image tag is:

```
<img id="zoom_01"
 src='New folder/small/image.jpg'
 data-zoom-image="New folder/large/image.jpg">
```

and elevatezoom script is:

```
<script>
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({scrollZoom : true});
</script>
```

I have many images that I want to zoom, with same id,src value is changing but I couldn't change  data-zoom-image value.How do change data-zoom-image value,you can also visit any [e coomerce website]that what I'm trying to tell.[1](http://flipcart.com)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After change of data zoom-image attribute, you need to re-initialize with `elevateZoom` like this:

```
$("#zoom_01").data('zoom-image', 'newURL').elevateZoom({
   responsive: true,
   zoomType: "lens", 
   containLensZoom: true
});
```

Comment: I know this is way old, but I wanted you to know that this was a godsend.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hello I get this error: index.html:218 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).elevateZoom is not a function
    at myFunction (index.html:218)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (index.html:168)

Comment: @FernandoPie, have you included jQuery and the plugin on a page? See demo here: https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/blob/master/demo.html#L6-L7

Answer (score 6):

If you want change image which shown as zoomed, simply do this

```
$('.zoomWindowContainer div').stop().css("background-image","url("+ changed_image +")");
```

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for changing the zoomed image with elevateZoom plugin after changing the zoomed thumbnail image.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this...

```
$("#zoom_01").attr('data-zoom-image', 'new path');
```

Comment: It's not working... data-zoom-image is not actual attribute used in img tag.I downloaded elevate zoom.

Comment: even if it is not original attribute. It should work. Please share some code where you are trying to modify the tag and the src of the image

Comment: I have three small  images as thumbnails and one big image...
this is one of the small image <img src="New folder/images/simage.JPG" data-zoom-image="New folder/images/bimage.JPG" />.I want to change Big image's data-zoom-image value with small image's data-zoom-image

Comment: this function is called on onClick of small image tag,  
function changeImg(src,id)
{
document.getElementById(id).src=src;
$(id).attr('data-zoom-image',src);
}

Comment: I think you need to add `#` sign before id while using JQuery. `$('#' + id).attr(...)`

Comment: It still not working,data-zoom-image still taking old value...
function changeImg(src,id)
{
 document.getElementById(id).src=src;
 $('#'+id).attr('data-zoom-image',src);

}

Comment: Because you are assigning the same source to both the `image-src` and `data-zoom-image`. You need to give the high res. image source to `data-zoom-image`

Comment: Yes data-zoom-image has similar value as src,because their initial value are same,and I want to change both the attr with same value.

Comment: You need to give a higher resolution image for data-zoom-image to work on. If both src and data zoom image have same image source the zoom will not work...

Comment: That means I need to pass one more parameter in changeImg function for higher res image...?

Comment: I used higher res image...but not working...
function changeImg(src,id,dz)
{
 document.getElementById(id).src=src;
 $("#"+id).attr('data-zoom-image',dz);

}
dz for higher res. image..

Comment: Is there any fault in mixing of `jquery` and `javscript` if you have another idea so please help...

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem here, figured it out: it probably doesn't work because the plugin doesn't support changing that particular attribute - it has its own gallery functionality. There are errors in their own documentation, this is how it works:

HTML for main image & thumbnails:

```
<img id="bigpic" src="small/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>

<div id="gal1">

<a href="#" data-image="small/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg">
<img src="thumb/image1.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="#" data-image="small/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/image2.jpg">
<img src="thumb/image2.jpg" />
</a>

</div>
```

jQuery for initializing the gallery:

```
$("#bigpic").elevateZoom({
gallery:'gal1',
galleryActiveClass: 'active'
```

- plus whatever other attributes you want to give it

jQuery for passing the images to the main container:

```
$("#bigpic").bind("click", function(e) {  
var ez =   $('#bigpic').data('elevateZoom');    
$.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
return false;
});
```

I'm new to jQuery and I don't really 100% understand the mechanics here, but that's how I got it to work, I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Include the following code in js and it may solve your problem
In variable smallImage give the url of the new small image 
and in largeImage give the url of new large image.
Hope this solves your problem without reintializing your elevate zoom.

```
var ez = $("#zoom_01").data("elevateZoom");
ez.swaptheimage(smallImage, largeImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have just to use the gallery feature provided by the plugin itself, just wrap your images into a container

```
<img src="img1-small.jpg" id="zoom_x" data-zoom-image="img1-large.jpg">
<div id="my_images">
<a href="#" data-image="img1-small.jpg" data-zoom-image="img1-large.jpg"><img src="img1-small.jpg" alt=""></a>
<a href="#" data-image="img2-small.jpg" data-zoom-image="img2-large.jpg"><img src="img2-small.jpg" alt=""></a>
...
</div>
```

then you have to call the plugin like this:

```
$("#zoom_x").elevateZoom({ gallery: "my_images", zoomType   : "inner", cursor: "crosshair", imageCrossfade: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var zoomElement = $('#zoom_01');

// destroy old one
zoomElement.removeData('zoom-image');
$('.zoomContainer').remove();

// set new one
zoomElement.attr('data-zoom-image', image_large_size);
zoomElement.attr('src', image_normal_size);

// reinitial elevatezoom
zoomElement.elevateZoom();
```