# Swap plugin's 'data-zoom-image' attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, zooming

I am using the Elevate Zoom plugin which shows the full size image when you hover over a thumbnail: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

I have some JQuery that swaps the thumbnail images src, eg:

HTML

```
<div id="primaryimage">
<img src="image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="image1.jpg"">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#prodimages img").click(function() {
     var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#primaryimage img").attr("src", imgsrc);
});
```

However, I cant seem to swap the `data-zoom-image` attribute to swap the larger, zoomed in image.

So far I have tried:

```
$("#primaryimage img").attr("data-zoom-image", imgsrc);
```

and

```
$("#primaryimage img").data("data-zoom-image", imgsrc);
```

and reactivating the plugin within the click function:

```
$("#primaryimage img").elevateZoom({
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
lensFadeIn: 500,
lensFadeOut: 500
});

$("#primaryimage img").data("data-zoom-image", imgsrc);
```

to no affect.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `$("#primaryimage img").data("data-zoom-image", imgsrc);` to `$("#primaryimage img").data("zoom-image", imgsrc);` as there is no need to append data when calling the `.data()` function

Comment: Thanks, but no luck there either

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here: [How to change data-zoom-image value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110330/how-to-change-data-zoom-image-value)

Had to re-initialise Elevate Zoom with new image url data.

My full code:

```
$("#prodimages img").click(function() {
     var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#primaryimage img").attr("src", imgsrc);


    $("#primaryimage img").data('zoom-image', imgsrc).elevateZoom({
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 500,
    lensFadeIn: 500,
    lensFadeOut: 500
    });

    $("#primaryimage img").data("zoom-image", imgsrc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to re-initialize Elevate zoom. Just swap the images by following supported code:

```
 var ez = $('#YourZoomId').data('elevateZoom');
 ez.swaptheimage(smallImageURL, largeImageURL);
```